# How to cause sqlite3_initialize to fail

Tags: c, unit-testing, sqlite

I have the following C code that uses sqlite3:

```
if(SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_initialize()) {
    self->db_open_result = sqlite3_open(self->db_uri, &(self->db));
} else {
    self->db_open_result = SQLITE_ERROR;
}
```

Obviously I have a pretty high confidence that the code is correct and will behave as expected. However, I am measuring code coverage of my unit tests using gcov/lcov and I'm curious about how I might get my coverage number to 100% in this case. Under normal circumstances `sqlite3_initialize()` is never going to fail, so the `else` clause will never execute.

Is there a way to cause this to fail that isn't totally disruptive?

Comment: "*If for some reason, sqlite3_initialize() is unable to initialize the library (perhaps it is unable to allocate a needed resource such as a mutex) it returns an error code other than SQLITE_OK.*" - maybe you can find the mutex it uses and open it first?

Comment: Does "totally disruptive" preclude prepending an 'x' on the front of ` sqlite3_initialize` to cause it to fail?

Comment: @DCoder that is the only thing I'm finding so far is to muck with the internals before that call.

Comment: @Ben Yes. But what I really meant by "disruptive" was things like doing a `malloc(ALL_MEMORY)` prior to the call. And obviously I could alter the sqlite3 library to include some sort of test case settings to allow it to intentionally fail... but then I have a whole new set of problems. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your unit-tests to test your code. But you also want to know that all of your test code has been properly exercised. One way to do that is to use "mocking", i.e. you replace your actual libraries (such as SQLite) with fake, or "mock" libraries and then run your programs against these fake libraries.

Whether this library replacement is done at compile time or runtime is really incidental, but in C it's easier to do it at compile time. You can do this mocking by hand, or you can use a tool such as [Cmock](http://throwtheswitch.org/white-papers/cmock-intro.html).

In the faked library, you then provoke various errors and failures. Notably, the faked library doesn't even have to *do* anything or even keep track of much or any state, you can often get quite far by returning "OK" or "FAIL".

Comment: I think this is probably the only real answer, but I was hoping to avoid it :) sqlite3 has an in-memory mode which makes it perfect for not having to mock one's database in order to do automated testing (I know, technically that pushes away from unit testing and into integration testing territory). Having to mock sqlite3 means running two separate compiles for my test code, one with the real sqlite3 and one with the mock. Probably not the end of the world. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to cause this to fail that isn't totally disruptive?

For portability reasons you should verify function success. What's happens if you not installed SQLite library? You cannot initialize the library if that happens.

"If for some reason, sqlite3_initialize() is unable to initialize the library (perhaps it is unable to allocate a needed resource such as a mutex) it returns an error code..."

So, if you want portability check the error.

Comment: If the library is not installed, the program won't even run because the runtime linker cannot resolve the `sqlite3_initialize` symbol (or it may run, depending on the specific OS/platform, but then "exit" prior to doing the call, because it is simply not there).